# How to manage password validation

Tags: kotlin, authentication, validation, passwords, letter

I'm trying to do password validation.
I did try this but not working well

My activity is;

```
class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    private var userId: EditText? = null
    private var userPassword: EditText? = null
    private var userIdLength: Int? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)

        userId = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.idText)
        userPassword = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.passwordText)

        userIdLength = userId!!.length()


    }



    private fun isValidPassword(password: String) : Boolean {
        if (password.length < (userIdLength?.plus(4)!!)) return false
        if (password.firstOrNull { it.isDigit() } == null) return false
        if (password.filter { it.isLetter() }.first() { it.isUpperCase() } == null) return false
        return true
    }



    fun login(view: View) {

        val id = userId!!.text.toString()
        val password = userPassword!!.text.toString()


        if (id.isEmpty()) {
            userId!!.error = "Id cant be empty!"
        }
        if (password.isEmpty()) {
            userPassword!!.error = "Password cant be empty!"
        }

        if (id.isEmpty() && password.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(this@LoginActivity, "Please enter id and password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show()
        }

        if (isValidPassword(password)) {
            val intent = Intent(this@LoginActivity, SaleActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
            finish()
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Password is invalid!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }


    }
}
```

My expactation is;''if userid is n, password ABCnn. for example if userid is 3 then password is ABC34. If the user id is 45 then password is ABC4546''

Can you help me for do that.

Comment: It seems quite strange that the password length depends on userId length, I don't remember any system or application with such restriction. If we can omit such condition, whole password validation can be performed using a regular expression.

Comment: @Andrey This is exactly what is asked for me;
 ''if userid is n, password ABCnn. for example if userid is 3 then password is ABC34. If the user id is 45 then password is ABC4546''
I'm trying to do this.

Comment: could you please clarify the all requirements? "My expactation is, If userId.length = 3 , password needs to be 3 upper letter + userId.length + 1" is contrary to what you specified in the comment above

Comment: @Andrey I guess, I didnt make myself clear.I’m editing now. My last comment is exactly what asked for me. Sorry for the confusion.